# how to position an image vertically centered with percentages

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to center an image horizontally and vertically in a div. I have read a lot however I couldn't find anything about using it positions with percantages. This is my html:

```
<div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three">
    <img src="http://www.medicalpracticeinsider.com/sites/default/files/News%20Box_0.jpg" id="img" />
    </div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

This is my css:

```
*{
    text-align: center;
}
#two{
    height:30%;
    background-color: green;
}
#three{
    height:30%;
    background-color: red;
}
#four{
    height:30%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#img{
    height: 50%;
    width: auto;
}
```

So horizontally, I center it with `text-align`. I tried using `vertically-align: middle;` for the `#img` which didn't work. Then I tried using `marign`, however, not sure what to use for the y. If I use it the left corner of the image starts in the middle of the page:

```
#three{
    position: relative;     
    height:30%;
    background-color: red;
    }
#img{
    height: 50%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

But nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons, your image is not being loaded on my jsfiddle, but you can try these `CSS` properties;

```
#img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 20px;  

}
```

Comment: I know, jsfiddle didn't work when I tried either. Thanks that works ! one questions though, why is padding with hardcoded px ?

Comment: well ? because it's an example and we are trying static css code ? you can do it dynamically too by javascript, like this; document.getElementById("#img").style.padding = "50px";

Comment: ah kk nvm I think that was a dumb question, i thought everyhting has to be in %

Comment: You use either em, px, or percentage depending on your layout and requirements, glad I could help Paul :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#img { 
margin: 0; 
display: block;
}
```